# Get function returned 2 values in Web3j

Tags: web3j

I wrapped a smart-contract generated in remix into a Java Project. Im trying to get the two values that return me this function.

```
function getValues(address _a) external returns(bool, uint32) {
    uint32 n= data[_a].number;
    return (true, n);
}
```

The problem is that the returned value is a TransactionReceipt. How can I recover bouth value; The boolean and the uint??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that the returned value is a transaction-receipt. How can I recover both values?

Add `view` to the function declaration, and the returned value will be a tuple `(bool, uint32)`.

Otherwise (if there's something that you're not telling us about the function, for which it cannot be declared `view`), you'll need to `emit` an event with the return values, and fetch it from the transaction-receipt.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. understood. Im going to open a new question because I dont know how to recover values of a event from web3j, if you can help me

Comment: @UnexpectedCharacter: So what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: I change the function visibility adding view to the function. When I wrapped the contract to a java class the error persist. And I have to manage the TransactionReceipt instead of a tuple T<boolean, BigInteger>

Comment: @UnexpectedCharacter: Are you sure that you have compiled (or rebuilt) the contract?

Comment: Yes I check and is done. Still returning TransactionReceipt

Comment: @UnexpectedCharacter: So what made the difference then?

Comment: Why do you have to emit an event, rather than just get the return result (of a non-view function)? If I use something like remix IDE, it's able to obtain the result of the function - with no events needed

Answer (score 2):

The function can be made `view` and then you can use `call` from web3. This won't make a transaction but will just execute the function on the node you are connected to. The result will be the values that you expect.

Hope this helps

Comment: I change the function and I add the view. But When I wrapp the contract to a Java class. Still telling me that I have a TransactionRecepit return. Any idea?

Comment: can you post your java script code?. remember you need to update the `ABI` in your code and use `call` with your contract method.

Comment: I´m not using web3js. The library is the web3j. I think that the call method is not implemented

Comment: i tell that because in the documentation I can´t find

Comment: It is implemented, you should use `EthCall method` an example of how to make a `call` to contracts can be found here: https://docs.web3j.io/transactions.html?highlight=ethcall#querying-the-state-of-a-smart-contract

Comment: docs for EthCall moved: https://docs.web3j.io/transactions/#querying-the-state-of-a-smart-contract